# Javascript code is running in a limited loop, need to refactor

Tags: javascript

I have a set of code that is working as intended, but my PR approver is telling me to refactor because it's running in a loop, and there should be a more efficient way to write the code. I'm still learning javascript, so often problems like this throw me for a loop (no pun intended), and I rely on the greater world of the internet for learning/help.

The code is meant to check a URL's domain against an array of 'valid' domains and return whether the URL's domain is valid (returns false) or invalid (returns true).

How do I go about refactoring this code so there is no loop in calling cleanupParams?

```
export const isValidLink = (hostname?: string, validDomains: string[] = []) => {
  return validDomains.every((domain) => {
    if (hostname && !hostname.startsWith("#")) {
      return cleanupParams(hostname).indexOf(domain) < 0;
    }
  });
};

const cleanupParams = (url: string) => {
  let domain = url;
  try {
    domain = new URL(url).hostname;
  } catch {
    domain = url;
  }
  return domain;
};
```

Comment: It's not super-clear what the method is trying to do, but if it's checking a hostname against a list of valid domains, `every` isn't [what you want](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every). You can stop after the first matching hit. There's no way to do it without *some* form of iterating against the array of valid domain strings, though, whether explicitly or via a `find` etc.

Comment: I agree with @DaveNewton if you're trying to check if there is an error you don't have to check whether **everything** is good, but it would be better to check if one is bad and then stop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The method `every` will run the callback method for each item in the array. The `hostname`, though, is not affected by the array , and so, should not need to be cleaned up each time. You should do that, once, outside the `every` loop.

```
export const isValidLink = (hostname?: string, validDomains: string[] = []) => {
  // early break if conditions are not met
  const isValidHostname = hostname && !hostname.startsWith("#");
  if (!isValidHostname) return false;

  const cleanedUpHostname = cleanupParams(hostname);  
  return validDomains.every((domain) => {
      return cleanedUpHostname.indexOf(domain) < 0;
  });
};
```

Comment: This is exactly what i typed, you anticipated me :D only difference is that i was using `return validDomains.includes(cleanedUpHostname );` instead of `every`, not sure which is better

Comment: @coglialoro not sure what is in `validDomains` and the original code would account for partial matches with the `indexOf`.